# firebase recycler view loading very slowly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

My Firebase `RecyclerView` takes too much time to load data. I used `RecyclerView` in many fragments, but they do not arise any problem. But I don't know what the problem is here. It loads data after 5 or more minutes. Any one know the problem?

**My main Fragment class**:

```
public class UserPrescriptionView extends Fragment {
    private DatabaseReference dataRef;
    private String uid;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Query mQuery;
    private RecyclerView recycle;
    private TextView noCnslt,dctName,cnsltDate;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
    container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (container!=null){
            container.removeAllViews();
        }
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_user_prescription_view,container,false);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        dataRef= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        uid=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        recycle= (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_view_recycle);
        noCnslt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.activity_user_prescription_noCnslt);
        recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        progress= (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_progress);
        noCnslt.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recycle.setLayoutManager(llm);
        recycle.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        dctName= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_dctName);
        cnsltDate= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_cnsltOn);
        dctName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        cnsltDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        mQuery=dataRef.child("Medical Record").orderByChild("uid").equalTo(uid);
         FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DocPrcptn,DocPrcptnViewHolder> adapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DocPrcptn, DocPrcptnViewHolder>(
                DocPrcptn.class,
                R.layout.user_prscrptn_view,
                DocPrcptnViewHolder.class,
                mQuery
                ) {
             @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(DocPrcptnViewHolder viewHolder, final DocPrcptn model, final int position) {
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    dctName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    cnsltDate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate().substring(0,11));
                    viewHolder.setDoctor("Dr "+model.getDoctor());

                final String key=getRef(position).getKey();
                viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        FragmentTransaction ft=getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        Prescription pc=new Prescription();
                        Bundle b=new Bundle();
                        b.putString("key",key);
                        pc.setArguments(b);
                        ft.replace(R.id.activity_user_prescription_recycle,pc);
                        ft.addToBackStack(null);
                        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                });

            }

            @Override
            public void onDataChanged() {
                if (getItemCount()==0){
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    noCnslt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }
                super.onDataChanged();
            }
        };

        recycle.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    public static class DocPrcptnViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView docName,docDate;
        public DocPrcptnViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            docName= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_view_name);
            docDate= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_prscptn_view_date);

        }
        public void setDoctor(String name){
             docName.setText(name);
        }
        public void setDate(String date){
            docDate.setText(date);
        }
    }
}
```

**My model class**:

```
public class DocPrcptn {
    public DocPrcptn() {
    }
    public String doctor,date;

    public DocPrcptn(String doctor, String date) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        this.doctor = doctor;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Any clues? Thanks.

Comment: first determine on which step the problem occurs - when you gt the data from the internet, or when you show it in recyclerview. After that your problem will be half as easier.

Comment: populateviewholder triggers after too much time later..ie.,my problem.But on the other hand, I use firebase recyclerview in many fragments.But,they have no problem

Comment: then I think that your data is taking too much to load. And it does not relate to RecyclerView at all. Try checking how long this data will take to appear without recyclerview.

Comment: Surpricely.,it loads when i lock my device.when i lock my device,data loads.How the error comes.?